# ListView collapse in CustomScrollView

Tags: android, listview

Hello I am new in Android development, and I've read various threads which talked about the fact that a `ListView` should not be inside a `Scrollview` and need to wrap in linear or relative layout.

But I have a this layout

```
<com.itmind.spac.spacapp.custom_extends.CustomScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/scrollViewreceipt"
>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/customers_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/venues_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/workgroup_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
        />

        <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="150dp">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/activityList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:minHeight="150dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout >

    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/signaturePad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="#d3d3d3"
        android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
        android:fadeEnabled="false"
        android:gestureColor="#333"
        android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="0.1"
        android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
        android:fadeOffset="5000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="testImage"
        android:text="testami"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my custoScrollView

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

private boolean enableScrolling = true;

public boolean isEnableScrolling() {
    return enableScrolling;
}

public void setEnableScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
    this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
}

public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if (isEnableScrolling()) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isEnableScrolling()) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I need customclass scroll view beacause I can set enable scroll when i touch on

so in my activity that implements GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener I have:

```
 @Override
public void onGestureStarted(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    myScrollView.setEnableScrolling(false);
}
@Override
public void onGestureEnded(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    myScrollView.setEnableScrolling(true);
}
```

So many elements and I need to scrollView for view all elements.
Inside my scrollView I have a listView that I populate with data retrieve from db.

My problem is that my Listview collapse, that shows one line and I see and scroll in one row.

I tried with `min-height` but doesn't work, and if I put a layout height in `Listview`, I cant scroll this list.

How can I do this?
I would a list View in a long page so I have to use scrollview or are there solutions?

Comment: Why are you using custom scroll view class? Paste its code.

Comment: Hello thankyou, I use customScrollview for <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView> 
I edit and paste my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below given custom `ListView` class will make height of your `Listview` based on its content inside `ScrollView`. Use it instead of `ListView` in your xml-layout file same way you use your `CustomScrollView`.

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {

//  private boolean expanded;

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

**Note :-** As per [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) link of Android developer website, We should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling.